# What is the number of triples (a, b, c) of positive integers such that the product $a.b.c=1000$ , and $a \leq b \leq c $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> What is the number of triples (a, b, c) of positive integers such that the product $a.b.c=1000$, and $a \leq b \leq c$?

My try:

The prime factorization of $1000$ is $2^3\cdot 5^3$

$a\cdot b \cdot c = 2^3\cdot 5^3$

$a=2^{a_1}\cdot 5^{a_2}$

$b=2^{b_1}\cdot 5^{b_2}$

$c=2^{c_1}\cdot 5^{c_2}$

$abc=2^{a_1+b_1+c_1}\cdot 5^{a_2+b_2+c_2}=2^3\cdot 5^3 $
$a_1+b_1+c_1=3$

How many ways are there such that $a_1+b_1+c_1=3$

Star's and Bar's  method: -

Number of ways to chose $2$ separators($0s$) in a string of $5 $$ = {5\choose 2 }=10$
$N(a_1+b_1+c_1=3)=10$
Similarly,  $N(a_2+b_2+c_2=3)=10$
$N(abc=1000)=10\cdot 10=\boxed{100}$

Is that okay ? Please write down any notes

Comment: Have you remembered to take into account the condition that $a\leq b\leq c$?  I think not.

Comment: @JMoravitz  I can't  understand what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $a,b,c$ you got 100 but that didn't take into account $a \le b \le c$.

So count $a=b=c$ that is $a=b=c=10$ you counted that once.  The remaining $99$ were overcounted.

Consider $a=b, c\ne a$.  Then $a=b= 2^j5^k; c=2^{3-2j}3^{3-2j}$ so there are $3$ such cases ($j = 0,1; k = 0,1$ but not $j=k=3-2j=3-2k= 1$).  You counted each of those $3$.  So that accounts for $9$ when you should have only counted $3$.  You have $90$ more to account for.

These are $a,b,c$ distinct.  You counted each of these $6$ times when you should have counted them once.  So you counted $90$ when you should have counted $15$.

So the number should be $15 + 3 + 1 = 19$.

Comment: You meant $c  = 2^{3 - 2j}3^{3 - 2\color{red}{k}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your computation of $N=10$ is correct and $100$ is the number of ordered triples that have product $1000$.  You have failed to account for the condition that $a \le b \le c$.  All of the unordered triples that have three distinct elements have shown up six times, so you have overcounted.  Those that have two or three equal elements have been counted differently.  Keep going.

Comment: okey , help me finish it , i got stuck here

Comment: You need to split into cases.  There is one set with all three equal, $a=b=c=10$.  How many are there with $a=b \neq c$ where we don't worry about whether $c$ is greater than or less than $a,b$?  How many times have you counted those?

Comment: Well count the the $a=b=c$.  That was counted once.  count the $a=b, c \ne b$ those were counted three times.  Divide them by 3.  That leaves $a,b,c$ distinct.  Those were counted 6 times.  Divide those by 6.

Comment: As a check:  In *Mathematica* `Solve[a b c == 1000  && 0 < a <= b <= c, Integers]` shows 19 solutions.

Comment: @Ross Millikan  can you elaborate the second case please ; so that i can complete the solution?

Comment: Can we write a general solution, for arbitrary $n$, without having to do the analysis "by hand"?  For instance, for $n=10^6$ the number of ways is $78$.  For $n = 10^9$ it is $517$.

Comment: ...and for $n=10^{12}$ it is $1405$.

Comment: @David G. Stork  how could that be possible  , please elaborate?

Comment: I can imagine an algorithm that takes input $n$, does a prime factorization, then automatically finds partitions of the exponents and thus finds candidate values for $a$, $b$ and $c$.  Then it eliminates the solution overcounting based on the combinatorics of the equality or inequality of $a$, $b$ and $c$.  After all, when you solve this "by hand," you're simply following logical, algorithmic steps.  Seems tricky to write it all out, but possible.  I can plot the number of solutions easily using *Mathematica*, however... but this is inefficient because it involves solving complex equations.

Comment: One case with $a=b\neq c$ is $1,1,100$.  The others look similar.  Once you decide on $a$ you know $b$ and $c=100/a^2$