# What is the number of ordered triplets (a,b,c), where a,b,c are positive integers (not necessarily distinct), such that $abc = 1000?$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> **QUESTION:** What is the number of ordered triplets (a,b,c), where a,b,c are positive integers (not necessarily distinct), such that $abc = 1000?$

---

**MY ANSWER:** Pardon me, this question has been asked before. I have a doubt as to why my approach gives an incorrect answer. This is what I did-

We know, $1000=2^3.5^3$
Now we have basically got 6 objects namely three $2's$ and three $5's$ to be arranged in 3 boxes a,b,c.
Now this is a simple problem. We assume that boxes may remain empty. Here empty denotes basically that the box has the number $1$, since multiplying $1$ with the others won't alter the product.

So the answer to that is $\binom{6+3-1}{3-1}$ which results in $28$. Now my logic is, whatever number falls inside a box, we multiply them. So that we get 1000 everytime at the end. Where am I wrong? How should I correct my answer?

Thank you for your help and support.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the number of triples (a, b, c) of positive integers such that the product $a.b.c=1000$ , and $a \leq b \leq c $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2356648/what-is-the-number-of-triples-a-b-c-of-positive-integers-such-that-the-produ)

Comment: Your error:  You can have $0$ $2$s in a box... and $0$ $5$s in a box....

Comment: Yes that does. I just want to know where my logic is wrong. I have stated the same in my answer. You may see. @Dietrich Burde

Comment: You're wrong because the $2$s and $5$s must be placed in the three boxes independently... they're distinguishable from each other.  So instead of ${{8}\choose{2}}$, you need ${{5}\choose{2}}^2$.  Your answer would be correct only if, say, all the $2$s needed to appear to the left of the $5$s.

Comment: Yes I have considered that. Suppose a box receives neither any $2$ nor any $5$, so that box is considered to have the value $1$.  So it does not affect the product. @David G. Stork

Comment: I almost got you. What do you mean by the term independently?.. I mean can I not consider that the 2's and 5's can go to the boxes in *any* order possible. Because at the end of the day, we are just multiplying the numbers, Isn't it? @mjqxxxx

Comment: @mjqxxxx ... Oh yes!!!!!! .. I got you!.. thank you so much for your help. :)